# Regex Lookbehind assertion - match link anchor text

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I have links like

```
<a href="#" class="social google">Google</a>
<a href="#" class="social yahoo">Yahoo</a>
<a href="#" class="social facebook">Facebook</a>
```

Now I want to `match only anchor text` using regex.
I mean it should match only Text Google in the first link.

I have tried this code.

```
(?<=<a href="#" class="social .+?">).+?(?=</a>)
```

But its not working as expected.

Can anyone give me the correct syntax?

Comment: Do you want only the a elements that have class="social"?

Comment: @Giri: Like I said in your previous question. It is not possible to match only the text inside the tag if the content and the class are arbitrary. There is simply no support.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes I do understand. But i'm looking for alternate solutions. I think this solution will work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14814906/736037

Comment: @Giri: It is the same as the solution the other user provide in the previous question (after edit).

Comment: @nhahtdh And I think its the same solution you mentioned. `Usually capturing groups would be sufficient for most replacement scenarios`. Since i'm new to regex I couldn't understand it in the first time

Comment: @nhahtdh If you don't mind, can you give me the syntax to capture the group. I mean this code is not working `<a href="#" class="social .+?">(.+?)</a>`

Comment: @Giri: After matching it - what are you trying to do? Without this information, I cannot suggest anything.

Comment: @nhahtdh I just want to replace the text. I'm using multiple cursors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24325/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-giri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using look-behind and look-ahead to exclude the parts you don't want, I suggest using a capture group to get only the part you want:

```
<a href="#" class="social .+?">(.+?)</a>
```

Conceptually, look-arounds are used for overlapping matches. It doesn't appear that you need their functionality here.

(Of course, the [usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) apply)

**Update:** this is not only an issue of best-practices.  A regex using look-behind will actually produce incorrect results, because it allows the look-behind portion to overlap other matches.  Consider this input:

```
<a href="#" class="social google">Google</a>

...

<a class="bad">foo</a>
```

Your regex will not only match "Google"; it will also match "foo" because the `.+?` that is supposed to match only part of the class string can expand all the way to another link in the text.

Comment: Hi when I use your code `<a href="#" class="social .+?">(.+?)</a>` it still selects the whole text with tags. Can you tell me whats wrong?

Comment: @Giri, you need to use the correct Boost function to get the captured subgroup instead of the whole thing.  I'm not a Boost user, but it looks like they show how to do that here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  "~<a(>| .*?>)(.*?)</a>~si"
```

or

```
   "/<a(>| .*?>)(.*?)</a>/"
```

php sample

```
  $notecomments ='<a id="234" class="asf">fdgsd</a> <a>fdgsd</a>';

  $output=preg_replace_callback(array("~<a(>| .*?>)(.*?)</a>~si"),function($matches){
       print_r($matches[2]);
       return '';
   },' '.$notecomments.' ');
```

this give you All anchor text

and this return only class="social"

```
  "#<a .*?class=\".*?social.*?\".*?>(.*?)</a>#"
```

sample

```
  $notecomments ='<a id="234" class="fas social ads">fdgsd</a> <a>fdgsd</a>';

  $output=preg_replace_callback(array("#<a .*?class=\".*?social.*?\".*?>(.*?)</a>#"),function($matches){

     print_r($matches);
 return '';},' '.$notecomments.' ');
```

Comment: Hi But i don't need all anchor text. I want only the a elements that have class="social"

Comment: @Giri Yes I Understand See change.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the correct results, but because you have other matching groups (?...) you matches also contain data you don't want.

You could try using the non-matching groups (?:...) and putting the what you would like to show up in the match within a group itself (.+?)

Comment: actually the variable-length look-behind can overlap between matches, causing the regex to erroneously match other links and other elements in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\<a .*?\>(.*?)\<\/a\>
```

Edit 1 - this regex matches the anchors that have css class "social":

```
\<a .*?class=".*?\bsocial\b.*?\>(.*?)\<\/a\>
```

Comment: Hi yes, I want only the a elements that have class="social"